# React Redux cannot pass props of a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

What im trying to achieve in here is to being able to click on a image and render that clicked movie’s info. The problem is the i can not find a way to match id of the clicked movie and the detailed movie. As a result the singleMovierequest has undefined id which causes 404 error. Here is codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-http-coy0w (Api key is typed as '???' intentionally). Here is movie and app components.

```
const Movie = (props) => {

const movie = props.singleMovie
const fetchMovie = props.initializeSingleMovie
useEffect(() => { fetchMovie(props.id) }, [props.id]) 

return (
    <div>
        <h2>{movie.title}</h2>
        <p>{movie.overview}</p>
    </div>
)
```

}
**render part of the app component:**

```
<Container>
        <h2>Movieapp</h2>
        <Router>
            <Menu />
            <Route exact path="/popular" render={() =>
                <PopularMovies />
            } />
            <Route exact path="/search" render={() =>
                <Movies />
            } />
            <Route exact path="/search/:id" render={(props) => <Movie key={props.match.params.id} />} />
            } />
            <Route exact path="/popular/:id" render={(props) => <Movie key={props.match.params.id} />} />
        </Router>

    </Container>
```

Comment: What ever you have written in Reducer is actually Actions. You need to write Reducer. Please follow the Redux docs.

Comment: Dİd you check the sandbox? There are reducers in the app. :)

Comment: I saw that and that is not how it should be.

Answer (score 1):

"initializeSingleMovie" is an action,You named it reducer but its an action,for the sake of solving this problem ,you have to use mapDisptachToProps and dispatch(it will access the store methods),below is a modifed Movie.js File.In future have a separate action folder for api hits.Compartmentalise more,hope it helps.

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { initializeSingleMovie } from '../reducers/singleMovieReducer'


const Movie = (props) => {

    console.log(props,"");


    const movie = props.singleMovie
    props.initializeSingleMovie(props.id)


    return (
        <div>
            <h2>{movie.title}</h2>
            <p>{movie.overview}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        singleMovie: state.singleMovie
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
   return {
   initializeSingleMovie: (id) => dispatch(initializeSingleMovie(id)),

   };
}; 

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDisptachToProps
)(Movie)
```

Comment: Well not really but thanks for your advice i will for sure create seperate action folders. Also i understand that its hard to help without api keys which i didnt provide in sandbox.

Comment: if you are getting data in bare api hits from postman or any other tool, then i believe in code ,you need to import action properly ,other wise it wont trigger.if you are not getting data in api ,then that's other case